# The React useState() hooks stores undefined always even the data that is to be stored logs correctly using console.log();

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Here is the where I am having the problem,

```
const handleCLick = () => {
        const parsedId = getYouTubeID(videoLink);
        console.log(parsedId);
        setVideoId(parsedId);
        console.log(videoId);
    }
```

Here when I am trying to log the 'parsedId' it logs the data correctly

```
ioNng23DkIM
```

And after using the setVideoId() function when I try to log the value it returns undefined

```
undefined
```

Here is a snap shot of the log output.

[image]

Home.js code:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import getYouTubeID from 'get-youtube-id';

function Home(props) {
    const [videoLink, setVideoLink] = useState();
    const [isBool, setBool] = useState(false);
    const [videoId, setVideoId] = useState();
    const urlRef = useRef();

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setVideoLink(event.target.value);
        if (urlRef.current.value === '') {
            alert('Please enter a URL');
            setBool(true);
        } else {
            setBool(false);
        }
    }

    const handleCLick = () => {
        const parsedId = getYouTubeID(videoLink);
        console.log(parsedId);
        setVideoId(parsedId);
        console.log(videoId);
    }

    return (
        <section className="homeLayout">
            <div className="logo-display">
                <img className="logo-img" alt="logo" src="./logo.png" />
                <h1>WatchIt</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="searchlayer">
                <form>
                    <input ref={urlRef} id="videoLink" placeholder="Enter the youtube video URL:" onBlur={handleChange} required />
                    <Link style={{ pointerEvents: isBool ? 'none' : 'initial' }} to={`/play?=${videoId}`} onClick={handleCLick}>Play</Link>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: `setVideoId` is asynchronous, so `videoId` doesn't get set immediatly

Comment: So what should I do to solve my problem ? @NickParsons

Comment: When `videoId` does eventually get set, your function will re-render with the value set. So there shouldn't be an issue, what is your problem exactly / what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use useEffect to solve your problem.

Use effect will listen to you state change n then you can perform logic in there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is because `setState` will set the value *eventually*, not immediately (Usually this means the update will be visible when the component is rendered again). If you want to do something after the value is set, you need to use `useEffect`.

Splitting your `handleClick` we get,

```
const handleCLick = () => {
    const parsedId = getYouTubeID(videoLink);
    console.log(parsedId);
    setVideoId(parsedId); // Queue the change for `videoId`
}

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(videoId); 
}, [videoId]); // Call this function when the value of `videoId` changes
```